# SQL Server 2016 installation - missing components

Tags: database, installation, sql-server-2016

We are at the moment struggling my coworker and me at installing SQL Server 2016 on our server. We are working in a small-medium sized enterprise (15-20 workers) and we decided to upgrade our old SQL Server 2008 R2 to the latest 2016. After the purchase and once the .ISO downloaded, we tried to upgrade the 2008 version directly to the 2016 following the step-by-step described on Microsoft Support forums. That did not work.

We then uninstalled everything related to 2008 or 2016 on our server. We ran the Wizard as mentioned by Microsoft but we dont' have the same steps. The most important difference is located on the "Feature Selection" one (Screenshot below). We do not see any items in this list at all. We are expecting things like "SQL Server Engine" or some sort of core datas that would help creating the base of the server.
The SharePoint is not our priority but if we uncheck the two boxes, the "Next>" step then prompts an error blocking us from going further.
If we proceed to complete the wizard like this, we are then unable to access to the database with the "SQL Server Management Console".

Sorry if this seems vague, we are no DB experts... :(

I can complement with a lot of additional informations. We would love to have somebody shedding some lights on the problem.
Thanks in advance.

[image: SQL Server Installation Step]

Comment: You will have a log file with all the details,what does that tell ?

Comment: Yes of course, thanks for the quick answer. Here you go: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2d6d3778aaa3d16d3eff2ad27a91dc9c

Comment: if we proceed to complete the wizard like this, we are then unable to access to the database with the "SQL Server Management Console".  ?? what is the error you are getting

Comment: Sorry I will rephrase myself: We tried to install the 2016 while the 2008 was still present on the server. The 2016 engine wasn't installed properly so the connection with the Console worked but connected with the old engine and ours old databases.
Since then we wiped everything to start fresh. No 2008/2016 are present now on the server. But we still can't install a fresh new 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to answer to my question by a question :

I think I found the inherent problem. It may be stupid but can somebody confirm me that there is not way possible to install a 'SQL Server 2016' on an OS 'Windows Server 2008 R8'?

Thanks